# General text encoding program in Java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I try to write a program which will take as an input some text and then the name of the target encoding (`ASCII`, `UTF-8`, etc.).

Is there any way in Java to write something like this?

```java
String encodedText = String.encode(text, encoding);
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `byte[] theBytes = text.getBytes(encoding);`. Strings are sequences of chars; the encoding is the mapping of that to a sequence of bytes.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to convert from `byte[]` to `String` with your intended character set.

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

or as [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) mentioned in the comments, you can use the `getBytes` method of the `String` class.

```
text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String decodeText(String input, String encoding) throws IOException {
    return 
      new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()), 
          Charset.forName(encoding)))
        .readLine();
}
```

Should do the trick.

Here is a well written post about how encoding works. I suggest you read through it before implementing this solution.
[Java-Char-Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for whole files you can make a loop which reads a line from a FileReader and writes it through a FileWriter. Both classes accept charsets to their constructors since java 11.